# Upper Bound Theorem for Simplicial Spheres

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, polytopes, simplicial-complex

I am recently approaching combinatorial commutative algebra and I am studing Upper Bound Theorem for Simplicial Spheres (Stanley 1975).
My question is so a bit general and maybe ingenuous...

Momentum curve is the algebraic curve $M \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ defined parametrically by
$x(\tau) = (\tau, \tau^2, ..., \tau^d) $.
A cyclic polytope $C(n, d)$ is the convex hull of any $n$ distinct points on $M$.

There is a first Proposition I have seen,that says any cyclic polytope is a symplicial $d$- polytope (since you can prove any $d+1$ dinstinct points on $M$ are affinely independent).

Question 1) Are there other algebraic curves with this property?

More over you can prove the combinatorial type of a cyclic polytope $C(n, d)$ depends only upon $n$ and $d$ and not on the particular vertex set $V \subset M$.

Question 2) Are there other algebraic curves with this property?

So the point is: I do not understand the peculiarity of momentum curve.
Maybe there is another curve $N$ such that if you take the convex hull of $n$ distinct points, call it $N(n, d)$, you can reformulate upper bound theorem for simplicial spheres in this way:

*Given $P$ a simplicial complex whose geometric realization is topologically a sphere, with n vertices, the following inequality holds: $f_j(P) \le f_j(N(n, d))$, where $f_j$ is any component of the $f$-vector.*

If such a curve does not exist, why?
I think McMullen's formulated the conjecture, so how did he find the momentum curve?

Thanks

Comment: This particular curve is simply very convenient to describe and (sort of) visualize. What really matters is the combinatorial type of the cyclic polytope.

Comment: The answer to Question 1 is *Yes*, but probably in an unsatisfactory way: $(\tau, 2\tau^2,3\tau^3,...,d\tau ^d)$ does the trick, and you can find other trivial modifications. Question 2 sounds interesting, but I expect the answer to be no.

Answer (score 1):

To your last (unnumbered) questions:

Suppose that such a function $N(n,d)$ exists with $f_i(P)\le f_i(N(n,d))$ for all simplicial spheres $P$.
This must in particular hold for the boundary complex of the cyclic polytope.
Therefore

$$f_i(C(n,d))\le f_i(N(n,d)).$$

But by the *upper bound theorem* for simplicial spheres (proven by Richard Stanley), we also have

$$f_i(N(n,d))\le f_i(C(n,d))$$

as well, establishing identity, and so $N(n,d)$ must be cyclic.